# MS SQL: How to get the latest date (billdate) before another date(paymentdate) for multiple users?

Tags: sql, sql-server

sample tables as follows:

table 1

```
userid |  billdate       
user1  |  2017-06-01  
user1  |  2017-05-01 
user1  |  2017-04-01 
user2  |  2017-06-01  
user2  |  2017-05-01
```

Table 2

```
userid |    paymentdate
user1  |   2017-06-01 
user1  |   2017-06-02
user1  |   2017-05-02
user2  |   2017-06-30
user2  |   2017-05-30
```

Desired output

```
userid |  billdate     | paymentdate
user1  |  2017-05-01   | 2017-06-01
user1  |  2017-06-01   | 2017-06-02
user1  |  2017-05-01   | 2017-05-02
user2  |  2017-06-01   | 2017-06-30
user2  |  2017-05-01   | 2017-05-30
```

Thanks in advance

added one more scenario: what if multiple payments on same month. and for every paymentdate, the previous bill date should be in desired output

Comment: What if `user1` has three records in `Table 2`

Comment: In my opinion you should link your payments to bills. I would never pay you if I don't get a bill so the link should always exist. So basicly you'd have to add a column "bill_ID" to the payment table. This one will have troubles if one transaction pays for multiple bills. You'd have to handle that on your front-end application

Comment: possible. but assuming user1 has only these records.

Comment: @Luke, yes that is the ideal way. but for past records i need to fetch data.

Comment: Addition to my first comment: If you do so use [joins](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Comment: thanks for the quick solutions. i really appreciate. i just added one more scenario for my case. if you modify your answer accordingly and help me out, i will be really grateful. added scenario - what if user1 has a billdate without a payment date. i don't need that row

Comment: In your desired output, for user1, you match 2 payments to 2017-05-01, so was it paid twice? And the bill for 2017-04-01 was never paid?

Comment: @robertdeniro, i am geting close to the answer with my real life case scenario thanks to answers of -iamdave and -prdp. will update once i confirm

Comment: @HopetoChristianChophi  My answer below gives your desired output exactly as given in your question.  What parts are not working for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to only return the records for where there is a `Bill` and a `Payment` record, then we first need to make some assumptions - namely that there will not be two `Payment` records between any two `Bill` payments, or that there will be two `Bill` payments on the same day.

Assuming all that, you can use `cross apply` to get the most recent `Payment` record for each `Bill` record, not returning anything where there is no `Payment` record available:

```
declare @Bills table(userid nvarchar(10),billdate date);
insert into @Bills values ('user1','2017-06-01'),('user1','2017-05-01'),('user1','2017-04-01'),('user2','2017-06-01'),('user2','2017-05-01');

declare @Payments table(userid nvarchar(10),paymentdate date);
insert into @Payments values ('user1','2017-06-01'),('user1','2017-06-02'),('user1','2017-05-02'),('user2','2017-06-30'),('user2','2017-05-30');

select p.userid
        ,ba.billdate
        ,p.paymentdate
from @Payments p
    cross apply(select top 1 billdate
                from @Bills b
                where p.userid = b.userid
                    and b.billdate < p.paymentdate
                order by b.billdate desc
                ) ba
order by p.userid
        ,ba.billdate desc
        ,p.paymentdate desc;
```

Output:

```
+--------+------------+-------------+
| userid |  billdate  | paymentdate |
+--------+------------+-------------+
| user1  | 2017-06-01 | 2017-06-02  |
| user1  | 2017-05-01 | 2017-06-01  |
| user1  | 2017-05-01 | 2017-05-02  |
| user2  | 2017-06-01 | 2017-06-30  |
| user2  | 2017-05-01 | 2017-05-30  |
+--------+------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply.what if there is multiple payments as it is there in my real life scenario. :)

Comment: @HopetoChristianChophi  Was updating my answer just as you were writing that comment :)

Comment: seems to be working..just confirming with my live db...some live scenario might have left out in the sample scenario...  will update the question if i can find it or else will mark it as answer after confirming. please give me some time. thanks again

Comment: Thank you all for the quick and detailed solutions provided. I have marked the solution by @iamdave which has worked for my scenario. i am overwhelmed with the quick response provided as this was my first question here.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to join the tables, but don't have a key.  `row_number()` can provide the key:

```
select t1.*, t2.paymentdate
from (select t1.*,
             row_number() over (partition by userid order by billdate) as seqnum
      from t1
     ) t1 join
     (select t2.*,
             row_number() over (partition by userid order by paymentdate) as seqnum
      from t2
     ) t2
    on t1.userid = t2.userid and t1.seqnum = t2.seqnum;
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to get all rows from Table01 and then get only one row from Table02 sorted ascending. Table02 rows are joined by userid and date (billdate <= paymentdate). Outer apply with top (1) will do the trick.

```
drop table if exists dbo.Table01;
drop table if exists dbo.Table02;

create table dbo.Table01 (
    userid varchar(100)
    , billdate date
);

create table dbo.Table02 (
    userid varchar(100)
    , paymentdate date
);

insert into dbo.Table01 (userid, billdate)
values ('user1', '2017-06-01'), ('user1', '2017-05-01')
    , ('user2', '2017-06-01'), ('user2', '2017-05-01');

insert into dbo.Table02 (userid, paymentdate)
values ('user1', '2017-06-02'), ('user1', '2017-05-02')
    , ('user2', '2017-06-30'), ('user2', '2017-05-30');


select
*
from dbo.Table01 t1
    outer apply (
            select
                top (1)
                t2.paymentdate
            from dbo.Table02 t2
            where t1.userid = t2.userid
                and t1.billdate <= t2.paymentdate
            order by t2.paymentdate asc
    ) tt
```

Comment: Whilst this script looks like it actually works, code only answers are generally frowned upon.  You need to explain what you are doing and why.

Comment: True, Just writing code into the answer will make StackOverflow look like a coding service which it definitly doesn't want to be. Having working code is great, but understanding it is indispensable.

Comment: You are still not explaining what you are doing...  If you think what you have added is sufficient to teach someone how your script works, you are probably better off simply not answering questions.

Comment: @iamdave, is it now ok? I would like to still be able to answer questions.

Answer (score -1):

There are two possible solutions:

## First

Merge the tables into one. This will make it much clearer which dates belong to which bill and which user. So that the desired output is the table that you are working with. If a user has been billed but not paid yet. The paymentdate is `NULL`.

## Second

Add a primary key to the `table 1` and use it as foreign key in table 2 like so:

`bill_id | userid |s  billdate 
1       | user1  |s  2017-06-01
2       | user1  |s  2017-05-01
3       | user2  |s  2017-06-01
4       | user2  |s  2017-05-01`

Table 2

`bill_id | userid |s    paymentdate
1       | user1  |s   2017-06-02
2       | user1  |s   2017-05-02
3       | user2  |s   2017-06-30
4       | user2  |s   2017-05-30`

Now you can easily get it with a join:

`SELECT table1.*, table2.paymentdate
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.bill_id = table2.bill_id;`

Comment: First solution won't work in practice due to the possibilty of multiple transactions for one bill, second solution is almost copy paste of my comment, and no solution due the OP needs the querry to fetch up data, not to build new.

Comment: If the intention was to have multiple payments there is no way around a foreign key table. And sorry for copying you. Haven't seen your comment.

Comment: To just have multiple payments you will only need the FK-Column. You can have multiple payment rows linked to one bill row. You will only need an additional table to also have multiple bills for one payment which in reallife is a possible scenario.